# Couldn't find "libgojni.so"

Tags: java, android, go, gradle, gomobile

After importing a third party library into my Android project, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp-dAIPtULcj_wzNu8vrPvI5Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myapp-dAIPtULcj_wzNu8vrPvI5Q==/lib/arm, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libgojni.so"
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1011)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1657)
    at go.Seq.<clinit>(Seq.java:37)
    at go.Seq.touch(Seq.java:50)
    at com.fiskaly.kassensichv.sma.Sma.<clinit>(Sma.java:11)
    at com.fiskaly.kassensichv.sma.Sma.invoke(Native Method)
```

I think this library needs GO to function properly.

How can I implement the GO or better GO MOBILE dependency to my Android project?
Can I do it via maven or gradle?

Comment: What does this library do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These have to added as `src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libgojni.so` & `src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libgojni.so` (`jniLibs.srcDir` defines that path). [golang/mobile](https://github.com/golang/mobile) has examples. If these are custom JNI bindings, generated with [`gobind`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gobind), the native assembly (matching this mysterious 3rd party library) still would need to be placed at the expected locations.